# iOS, app randomly crashes on startup

Tags: ios, xcode

From a few days my new project crashes during startup iOS Simulator. However, if starts then works properly.

Error(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) is shown for these steps:

0:

```
0x9171ba6a:  jae    0x9171ba7a                ; __pthread_kill + 26
```

1:

```
0x94093b2f:  cmpl   $-1, %eax
```

2:

```
0x196757b:  jmp    0x19675aa                 ; abort + 187
```

3:

```
GraphicsServices`GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort:
```

4:

```
0x226e69f:  movl   %eax, 51254(%edi)
```

5:

```
0x226ec1f:  addl   $24, %esp
```

6:

```
0x2bfd99:  movl   7636317(%esi), %eax
```

and in the main.m:
7:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([cysAppDelegate class]));
```

What can cause this error?

Screen:[image: Error]

Comment: That's not enough information; post a *symbolic* stack trace and also the exception text generated.

Comment: Reset your simulator and check is it still occurring.

Comment: I added a screenshot with error screen. After reset my simulator error is still occuring.

Comment: ok solved by changing debug mode from LLDB to GDB.